# Can KVM work without libvirt?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I am sorry for silly question, but could you please tell: can KVM work without 
libvirt?

From my poor experience I have seen KVM functionality which based on libvirt.

Thanks for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used KVM without libvirt. libvirt is just a group that you assign a user to so that you are not rooted when you execute the virtual machine. You have to have qemu installed.

```
sudo apt-get install qemu
```

Then you would use the qemu package that supports the type of iso you are trying to install. Then you would write something like this

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -cdrom /path/to/Windows10.iso -enable-kvm
```

If you already have windows extracted onto the hard drive then you would write it like this

```
 qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -hda /path/to/Windows10.iso -enable-kvm
```

You can find out the different kinds of qemu packages that you have just typing in `qemu` in the terminal, and this will tell you the types of OSes that can be run inside of KVM using the specified package.

Comment: Please mark the check if that answered your question.